# SSRS Sum Textbox in Header

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an ssrs report in which I created a textbox in the header to sum a textbox which is in the matrix. When I run the report, I get a number that is way off. However, when I export this to Excel, the number shows correctly. I have to use the textbox to sum, because there a duplicate values that I don't want to sum. I've tried changing the number formatting to general, number, and currency, but still the same thing. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is advised not to have any dynamically calculated values in the page-header.
There are several approaches you can use to get your desired result.

1. Calculate the value outside the report and send it as a parameter to the reporter.
2. Place the textbox outside the page-header.

   - If you really need it as a header of the page, you can place a single row and column tablix (1x1) on your report and place rectangles inside the cells. Then you can use the top row as your page-header and size the bottom rectangle to be the same hight and with as your page and place everything inside it.
     This will then still look the same as your original page but won't use the page-header. Instead you'll have the table header-row at your disposal.

Feel free to leave a comment if you have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a total text box at the bottom of your matrix, make a note of name in the properties....ie: "Textbox5"
2. Add a new text box in the page header
3. set the expression to "=ReportItems!Textbox5.Value"

Answer (score 0):

that works thank you

f you really need it as a header of the page, you can place a single row and column tablix (1x1) on your report and place rectangles inside the cells. Then you can use the top row as your page-header and size the bottom rectangle to be the same hight and with as your page and place everything inside it.